# Azure DevOps Pipelines - how agents in an agent pool are selected for running jobs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, jobs, agent, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have the following question on how jobs are scheduled onto agents in an Agent pool.

**AzDO Job Scheduling on Agents**

This pertains to HOW the AzDO pipeline decides to pick which of the agents from the pool to run jobs.
The expectation is that jobs will be evenly distributed across the agents in the pool. However, we are noticing that only one of the agents is repeatedly the target of job executions, and this is skewing up the agent usage and rest of the agents are idling, while jobs are waiting.
I examined if there are any demand/capabilities placed on the agents and there are none.
**Questions: -**

1. What is the algorithm or job scheduling policy used to pick the
   agents? Is there any default stickiness once the job starts landing
   in an agent, meaning once an agent is selected from a pool then
   subsequent jobs get sticky to the same agent?
2. Why is only a single agent out of multiple agents in a pool getting used, while rest of agents are idling.

Comment: Regarding the finding 1 I have noticed the same on my private agent pools on Azure DevOps. Many times the same agent is picked up for subsequent jobs although other agents are also idle. I cannot interpet this behavior. Regarding your second point, I have not noticed this and all agents on my agent pool get utilized when multiple jobs are initiated.

Comment: Can your pipeline actually be running in parallel? At least in the classic pipelines there was way to limit parallelism to 1 pipeline run at a time

Answer (score 1):

ADO does not pick an agent. The agents "ask" ADO if there is new work for them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#communication-with-azure-pipelines

You mention "jobs". I'm not sure if you mean the technical term of an ADO job. If so: Jobs belong to a stage. An entire stage will always be executed on the same agents. Subsequent stages might be running on different agents.

I assume you are not using "[Capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#capabilities)"?! Otherwise that might explain the behavior that you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry - I should have been clear. By jobs I meant the entire Pipeline. As I mentioned no capabilities have been set on the agents or demanded by the pipelines. So, it still does not answer why a single agent is pulling in the pipeline when multiple others are available.

Comment: @GirishPillai lets call the agent that picks the jobs A. Do other pipelines runs are queued when agent A is working? (building, releasing) ? If no, I can give a potential explanation for this behavior but I am not pretty sure of it

Comment: @GeralexGR - Yes there are other pipeline runs queued when Agen A is working. 

In any case, please provide the explanation in case there are no queued jobs waiting.

Comment: @GirishPillai first things first, are you eligible for more than one parallel jobs? This should define how much pipelines could not the same time. You can locate this setting on Project settings -> Parallel jobs. If you are eligible only for one job at the time, that is why the rest of the agents on agent pool are idle. Then it is explained why the agent that finishes the job, will again begin the next run

Comment: This answer is not precisely correct.  ADO *does* pick an agent for a job to run on, but ADO does not initiate a network connection to the agent in order to start the job, instead it waits for the agent to query whether there's any available work for it to do.  That's why if you have a pool of 5 agents and you execute a pipeline 5 times in that pool, waiting to queue the next until the previous has finished, all 5 executions will run on a single agent.  I really wish ADO did round-robin scheduling but it doesn't.  It picks the first available agent from an ordered list of some sort.

Comment: @EricLee please add references that provide proof to your claim